# Segmentation fault when opening files

Tags: c, file, segmentation-fault, coredump

So, I'm trying to open 2 files that each have three lines and 2 numbers. After compiling, I run it in Terminal (I'm using Ubuntu ftr) as

```
./a.out a.txt+b.txt
```

And it returns nothing. When I comment out the "check if it opens properly" part of the code, it just spits out some numbers and prints out an error "Segmentation fault (core dumped) ". I really don't know what I'm doing wrong since this bit of code runs fine for my friends. I supply the offending bit of code bellow. (The rest of the code is supposed to run operations on the numbers and this is why there's a plus in between file names.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    FILE* fa = fopen(argv[1],"r"); if(!fa)exit(1);
    FILE* fb = fopen(argv[3],"r"); if(!fb)exit(1); 
    int k;
    double A[3];
    double Ag[3];
    double B[3];
    double Bg[3];

    for (k=0;k<3;k++){
        fscanf(fa, "%lf %lf", &A[k], &Ag[k]);
        fscanf(fa, "%lf %lf", &B[k], &Bg[k]);
    }
    for (k=0;k<3;k++){
        printf("%lf %lf\n", A[k], Ag[k]);
        printf("%lf %lf\n", B[k], Bg[k]);
    }
    fclose(fa);
    fclose(fb);

return 0;}
```

Comment: You need to separate arguments with spaces

Comment: You want `a.out a.txt + b.txt`

Comment: Check `argc` to avoid attempting to access arguments that do not, in fact, exist.  Do this in *every* program that uses command-line arguments.

Comment: ohhhhhhhh
okay, that works now, but it still breaks down and doesn't read some lines from the file (those are those last loops)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(In addition to the other answer:) this part of your code,

```
for (k=0;k<3;k++){
    fscanf(fa, "%lf %lf", &A[k], &Ag[k]);
    fscanf(fa, "%lf %lf", &B[k], &Bg[k]);
}
```

attempts to read from `fa` six times. Presumably you meant to read from `fb` in that second line.

Answer (score 2):

With `./a.out a.txt+b.txt`, you are passing two parameters (i.e. the executable name `./a.out` and `a.txt+b.txt`, not three. So when you access `FILE* fb = fopen(argv[3],...`, you exceed the bounds of `argv` and yield undefined behaviour.

Always check `argc` before accessing `argv`, and keep on checking NULL values:

```
if (argc < 3) {
   printf("wrong number of arguments.");
   exit(1);
}
FILE* fa = fopen(argv[1],"r"); if(!fa)exit(1);
FILE* fb = fopen(argv[2],"r"); if(!fb)exit(1);
```

And then - to pass two file names - call it like

```
./a.out a.txt b.txt
```